# Javascript/ Jquery: Get element from string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a editable div with HTML within it. When the user submits the form, the text is stored within a variable. I want to remove an attribute from this variable, and anything within it.

I've tried giving the HTML inside the div an ID and setting the **.innerHTML** to nothing, but it still doesn't work.

**My Code:**

```
var table = document.getElementById("fileTable");
table.innerHTML = '';
```

**This still returns the complete HTML:**

```
<table id="fileTable" fileid="41" type="1" taskid="1" class="table table-striped clearfix" role="presentation" contenteditable="false">
  <tbody class="files"><tr class="template-upload">
    <td><span class="preview"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/L9yd8dE.gif" height="80" width="57"></span></td>
    <td><p class="name">filename-1 2.pdf</p></td>
    <td><p class="size">309074</p></td>
    <td><a class="btn btn-sm red" href="#">Delete<i class="fa fa-exclamation"></i></a></td></tr>
  </tbody></table>
```

In addition, I've tried using jquery **.remove()** and **.empty()**, but it still wont remove the table from the editable div.

```
<div contentEditable=true id="commentPrivate" class="form-control todo-taskbody-taskdesc editableDiv" rows="4" data-ph="Type comment..."></div>
```

Here is more of the code in a pastebin : http://pastebin.com/sdif5paz

Can we remove the table tags and anything within it from a specified string?

Comment: Could you show more code?

Comment: @Stuart.Sklinar Certainly, pastebin incoming!

Comment: Can't you just add (Or at least more of it) here? It gives the whole thing much more context....?

Comment: Even better is a working example - JSFiddle :D

Comment: can you please show how are you making div editable and storing table inside a variable.

Comment: @Stuart.Sklinar Added more of the code, let me know if you need any more.

Comment: @Toby That pastebin url is not yours.

Comment: @artm What do you mean? It's taking me to the pastebin I just created

Comment: I'm sorry - but that is a total mess. 1) Formatting, where is it? 2) Context? 3) The code doesn't even work properly - see http://jsfiddle.net/qfvmak8c/ - I'll add this as seperate files to see what I can do - not cool.

Comment: Your JS has an error - you've not closed the last brace, so no doubt you're getting JS errors - have you tried debugging? Hint.... http://pastebin.com/pQXTfHjV

Comment: OK - See my answer, I've fixed your code - it turns out you had a missing bracket, something we would have never had seen, without posting mode of the code, to add some context. Also, if you are submitting code, please make sure it's properly formatted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove table directly form string using `substr()`

```
var myString = "smth <table>asdasdasd</table>smth else";
var firstPart =  myString.substr(0,myString.indexOf('<table>'));
var secondPart = myString.substr(myString.lastIndexOf('</table>')+8);
myString = firstPart + secondPart;
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jm4m2g9z/1/)

**UPD** and for removing table from DOM i'd use either jQuery method:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#tableId').remove();
})
```

or pure js:

```
var table = document.getElementById('tableId');
table.parentNode.removeChild(table);
```

Answer (score 2):

Removing the table seems to work okay for me. Did you wait for the dom to load, you can use $(document).ready() or window.onload

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/StevenIseki/8y6dkbms/)

```
window.onload = function () {
    var table = document.getElementById("fileTable");
    table.innerHTML = 'I removed the table';
    console.log(table);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After reading the FULL CODE it turns out you have a curly brace missing:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
      function privateComment(){
         var file = 0;
         var message = document.getElementById("commentPrivate").innerHTML;
         if(message.indexOf("contenteditable") > -1){
             var table = document.getElementById("fileTable");

             var type = table.getAttribute("type");
             var file_id = table.getAttribute("fileId");
             var taskId = table.getAttribute("taskId");
             table.innerHTML = '';
             var string = string +  '{"type": "' + type + '", "file_id": "' + file_id + '", "taskId": "' + taskId + '"}';
             var file = 1;
          } // <<< THIS IS NOT THE LAST BRACE
         var taskId = document.getElementById('form-task-title').getAttribute('showing');
         var button = document.getElementById("submit-private-comment");
         alert(message);
     }   //<<ADD THIS BRACE .

  </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but at the bottom of the pastebin I put "//cut off the code here.". I'll make it clearer next time. Thanks again!

Comment: NP - If you're giving code, give the full context- or create it small so someone else can just pick it up and run it (it took me about 20 mins to get it together!)